# Convert hard coded position to percentage position

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to put one element on the other and it's look as I want, but the problem is that the position of the elements is hard coded as you can see in the html and css below:

### HTML:

```
<div class="container text-center center">
    <div class="carouselContainer">
        <div id="carousel" class="carousel slide">
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            </ol>
            <div class="carousel-inner text-center">
                <div class="active item">
                    <img src="images/carusel_1.png" />
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="images/carusel_2.png" />
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="images/carusel_3.png" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

### CSS:

```
.container
{
    width: 1084px;
}

.carouselContainer
{
    background-image: url("images/carusel_wrapper.png");
    position: relative;
    top: 0; 
    left: 0;
    width: 1084px;
    height: 430px;

}

.carousel
{
    position: relative;
    width: 930px;
    top: 80px;
    left: 75px;
}
```

how can I make it responsive by making it position set by percentage . The inner image (of the planets) is located in the canter image of the frame (the frame with the arrows).

**Note**
I am using bootstrap.
[image]

Comment: The way to work out % is to do target / context = result. So if your container is 1000px and something inside is say 250px then 250/1000= 0.25 then move decimal right 2 points for 25%. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way would be to make every thing, including the sizes of your images in % with max-width and max-height, along with min-width and min-height to set specific and reasonable bounds: the max attributes so that the image wouldn't look bad, and the min for it not to collapse on one another.

After that, You just need to set everything with % as the value of the various positions and you're set.

If you could provide a fiddle with your code, i'll happily edit my question with the suggestion above.

Comment: here is the link to fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MgcDU/7901/. I don't know how to make bootstrap work there...